# Integrating bootstrap and materialize css in separate React components

Tags: css, reactjs

I know this is a very bad approach when we try to add two different css frameworks in a single project. But for now, due to a project requirement, I need to add bootstrap and materialize css in a project. In root component bootstrap is used, and in child component I will use materialize.

In child component I have included materialize in the following way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {findDOMNode} from 'react-dom';
import screenFull from 'screenfull';
import material from 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css';
import './Control.css';
```

but adding this way overlaps bootstrap classes which is obviously not the required behaviour.

I want to limit scope of materialize.css inside the child component only. Can anyone give me a suggestion on this?

**Note:** Root component was developed before, and create-react-app is not used over there. webpack configuration file has been written manually.

Comment: For your solution I would suggest you to use only one common framework. As you have mentioned that you have the code which have bootstrap I recommended you to us [link](https://mdbootstrap.com/)https://mdbootstrap.com/[/link] for your application so you application will looks goos and you don't have to replace the old bootstrap call and the old design will be converted to materialize without the any change in old bootstrap code as this library supports the bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ for your project as it's based on the bootstrap the UI will have look and feel like material and you haven't to change the existing code. I recommended to use only one UI framework for you project.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I need Materialize css as my child component includes a custom built player, where progress bar uses the materialize slider. Other than that we are using all bootstrap there. We want to keep the materialize slider here. is there any way to keep materialize scoped to a component only ?

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen that you are facing a problem where you need to include both the css framework, I better suggest you to use https://mdbootstrap.com/.

The second thing which I suggest you is to include in your application not for specific component. If you want to make some change for specific component look and feel create separate css/scss file and include it to you component.